TikZ: make a nice pattern at a smal area if using \usetikzlibrary{patterns}

How can I make a nice pattern if I use \usetikzlibrary{patterns} (if possible not \usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta})? 
E.g. pattern lines not so thick and no overlap and smaler line distances.
I don't find the keys in the file tikzlibrarypatterns.code.tex
If I set \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\cardwidth{0.61em} and then line width=0.025*\cardwidth this has no effect.
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\cardwidth{0.61em}% card width
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\cardheight{9*\cardwidth/6}% card height
\begin{document}

text
\begin{tikzpicture}[
mypattern/.style={%
fill=violet!22, 
postaction={
pattern=crosshatch, 
%pattern=north east lines, % alternativ
pattern color=violet,  draw=none,
line width=0.025*\cardwidth, % <---- no effect..........
},   },%
]
\node[minimum width=\cardwidth, minimum height=\cardheight, 
draw, rounded corners=0.075*\cardwidth, 
line width=0.025*\cardwidth,% <---- line width of node frame
mypattern,
]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
text
\end{document}

